# SAPUI5: How to update or clear cache of Homescreen application on iOS

Tags: ios, ipad, sapui5

I have developed two sapui5 Web applications and I have folowing problem on **iPad/iPhone** after saving a Web application as Homescreen App:

Changes in the source code of the appliaction don't affect the homescreen App. Clearing the cache of the Safari also had no effect to the homescreen application. I tried to delete the homeicon and then create it new from the updated Web App version but the new created homescreen application is still running with the same old logic and data it had by the first creation.

Is there any way to bring my sapui5 homescreen application to updated and or to clear its cache?
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I lost a lot of time before finding the method:

- Connect your device to your Mac
- Launch Safari with Development settings
- Launch your app on your device
- Open console on Safari: Development > Your device > Tour app
- In console tab: CMD + SHIFT + R
- In resource tab: Same with the refresh icon